# monitoring tools for gg

Tags: sqlplus, oracle-golden-gate

Are there monitoring tools available for Oracle GoldenGate?
tools to show how many rows from source are replicate to target.

I would like a tool to view the number of rows for a specific table at a particular timestamp from an extractor.

Answer (score -1):

The basic tool for monitoring Oracle GoldenGate is of course [Oracle Enterprise Manager](https://www.oracle.com/enterprise-manager/).